# How to display human readable Solr results

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

I was simply wondering if there's some plugin or feature I'm missing that would make Solr's indexing a bit more human readable. I've used the in build browse feature however it's still very technical and verbose.

Is there any option out there similar to how OpenGrok would present data?

Comment: what do you want to see? what do you mean by readable?

Comment: For example Solritas is never meant to be user facing. I have found a solution, however, with http://projectblacklight.org/